# Nnanomsg bus routing support?

Tags: nanomsg

I have been using NNG (C++) - now I need to write a C# plugin to read the NNG NanoMSG messages. But I am moving from pub/sub to a bus/mesh protocol. e.g.

https://nanomsg.org/gettingstarted/bus.html

1. Does nnanomsg support that?
2. What switches on the socket (options do I need) e.g. NN_BUS? NN_SOL_SOCKET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why the question should be marked negative. Although no one answered, I went implemented it with: https://github.com/mhowlett/NNanomsg

and the answers to the questions are:

1. Yes NNanomsg works fine with C++ NNG
2. Yes it has no problem with BUS protocols, and there are examples in the github.

Answer (score 0):

[The last PR merged](https://github.com/mhowlett/NNanomsg/pull/31) included a [Bus example](https://github.com/mhowlett/NNanomsg/blob/master/Example/Bus.cs).  That said, I haven't used the Bus protocol.

If you're using nng, there's also a C# wrapper for that called [csnng](https://github.com/mwpowellhtx/csnng).  I believe it doesn't include the nanomsg "compat" API, but [it includes the nng bus protocol](https://github.com/mwpowellhtx/csnng/tree/master/src/Nanomsg2.Sharp/Protocols/Bus).

Not that it's a substantial amount of work, but I forked both [NNanomsg](https://github.com/zplus/NNanomsg) and [csnng](https://github.com/zplus/csnng) to make .Net Standard libraries.